# Can I still purchase 4G/unlimited SIM card once I leave the airport in South Korea?

Tags: airports, cellphones, south-korea, internet

I want to purchase a mobile prepaid SIM card in Seoul but I missed my chance at Incheon Airport as I arrived at the counter just 2 minites before it is closed.

So I tried purchasing it once I enter the city, but out of three major carriers, SK Telecom and LGU+ declined it since they cannot sell it for travellers. As to olleh, they sell but only a limited data plan. At the airport, they offer an unlimited plan so I declined it.

Also some of them encouraged me to purchase EG SIM which is sold at convenience stores, but since I hate 3G and it is not unlimited plan, it is not within my choices.

So my question is the following:

- Can I still purchase it once I left the airport?
- Can I go back to the airport just to purchase it? It is no longer the arrival date but does it have any problems?
- If I can go back to purchase it at the airport, can I purchase it at Gimpo Airport, not Incheon, which I arrived at?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, since it is near impossible for me to live without stable, high-speed mobile network with unlimited data and tethering, I tried going back to the airport just to purchase the SIM card.

### Result? Yes, you can purchase it at the airport once you left it.

When I returned back to the airport and asked the counter, I didn't disclose that I haven't arrived at the purchase date. It seemed that she must check only the profile page (including a photo and ID) and didn't check out the arrival date.

Because I was so desperate for the SIM card and must avoid any potential flag, I went to Incheon, not Gimpo. So I don't know if it is possible to buy it at Gimpo, but from what I mentioned above, they seemed to not confirm it.

---

#### UPDATE

Well, according to [this post](https://www.trazy.com/experience/detail/korea-sim-card-unlimited-data?utm_source=Blog&utm_medium=blog-simcardunlimitedlte&utm_campaign=160724-blog-simcardunlimitedlte), it seems that you can purchase it at another counter at Incheon International Airport **even after it is over PM 10:00!** Also, it seems available at Hongik University Station. I wish I knew it in advance...

If I have any chance to visit them down the road, I will update it again.